# Как корректно передать указатель на массив в .Net

Tags: c#, .net, marshal

у меня есть структура на С++

```
struct {
      CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAGS Flags;
      NTSTATUS                                 CompletionStatus;
      LARGE_INTEGER                            PlaceholderTotalCount;
      CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO               *PlaceholderArray;
      DWORD                                    PlaceholderCount;
      DWORD                                    EntriesProcessed;
    } TransferPlaceholders;
```

и маршалинг на c#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack =1)]
            public struct TRANSFERPLACEHOLDERS
            {
                /// <summary>Flags for transferring placeholders.</summary>
                public CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAGS Flags;

                /// <summary>The completion status of the operation.</summary>
                public NTStatus CompletionStatus;

                /// <summary>Total number of placeholders.</summary>
                public long PlaceholderTotalCount;

                /// <summary>An array of placeholders to be transferred.</summary>
                public IntPtr PlaceholderArray;

                /// <summary>The number of placeholders being transferred.</summary>
                public uint PlaceholderCount;

                /// <summary>The placeholder entries that have been processed.</summary>
                public uint EntriesProcessed;

            }
```

PlaceholderArray - в этой структуре это массив объектов структуры CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO.

я создаю объект TRANSFERPLACEHOLDERS и пытаюсь передать туда массив CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO следующим образом:

```
CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO[] tmparr = new CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO[2] { tmp, tmp2 };
IntPtr ptrPlaceholders = tmparr.MarshalToPtr(Marshal.AllocHGlobal, out _);

var transferPlaceholders = new CF_OPERATION_PARAMETERS.TRANSFERPLACEHOLDERS
                {
                    CompletionStatus = completionStatus,
                    PlaceholderArray = ptrPlaceholders,
                    PlaceholderCount = (uint)tmparr.Length,
                //    EntriesProcessed = 0,
                    PlaceholderTotalCount = (uint)tmparr.Length,
                    Flags = flags
                 };
```

Но в таком случае получаю Access Violation. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А если использовать не IntPtr, а массив?

Comment: Дело в том, что структура TRANSFERPLACEHOLDERS - это маршаллинг из С++. (Добавил структуру на С++ в код). Если есть возможность использовать массив, подскажите как ? Спасибо

Comment: struct {
      CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAGS Flags;
      NTSTATUS                                 CompletionStatus;
      LARGE_INTEGER                            PlaceholderTotalCount;
      CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO               *PlaceholderArray;
      DWORD                                    PlaceholderCount;
      DWORD                                    EntriesProcessed;
    } TransferPlaceholders;

Comment: Так нельзя `public CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO[] PlaceholderArray;`?

Comment: В принципе можно, но тогда нужно будет менять часть другого кода в проекте. Можно ли все таки с IntPtr ?

Comment: Попробуй использовать вместо AllocHGlobal StructureToPtr https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_StructureToPtr_System_Object_System_IntPtr_System_Boolean_ в связке с доп. атрибутами для маршалинга. типа [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=[whatever your size is]]

Comment: Спасибо Yakov! Но проблема, к сожалению, осталась..

Comment: [Vanara.PInvoke.CldApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vanara.PInvoke.CldApi)

Comment: Alexander Petrov, спасибо за ссылку. У этого проекта нет реализации заполнения структуры TRANSFERDATA, только её маршалинг

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно включить UNSAFE для проекта или использовать unsafe-блок в коде и оперировать привычной "*". Покажите импорт метода в который передаете эту структуру, по идее туда прямо массив и надо передавать, маршаллинг сам все сделает.

Comment: Массив туда передать не получится, так как из этой структуры формируется ещё одна структура. И тогда уже вызывается метод CfExecute.

```[DllImport(Lib.CldApi, SetLastError = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
[PInvokeData("cfapi.h", MSDNShortId = "6AC8958D-B060-4468-9811-9BAB0E6A06D3")]
public static extern HRESULT CfExecute(in CF_OPERATION_INFO OpInfo, ref CF_OPERATION_PARAMETERS OpParams);```